# Why isn't a tuple parameter being recognized on my function?

Tags: f#

**Why isn't a tuple parameter being recognized on my function?**

I have the following function:

```
let deposit depositType ((logTransaction:string -> string -> unit), (file:string)) =
    depositType |> makeInitialDeposit
                |> sprintf "Deposited: %f"
                |> logTransaction file
```

Note how the last argument of the function is a tuple:

```
((logTransaction:string -> string -> unit), (file:string))
```

I then attempt to invoke this function using the following:

```
let file = "c:\\myfile.txt"
(writeToFile, file) ||> deposit OneDollarBill
```

Yet, it's stating that it's not expecting a tuple. Instead, it's expecting:

> Expecting a (string -> string -> unit) -> string -> 'a

The complete error is here:

> Type mismatch. Expecting a
>       (string -> string -> unit) -> string -> 'a     but given a
>       (string -> string -> unit) * string -> unit     The type 'string -> string -> unit' does not match the type '(string -> string -> unit) * string'

**Here's the code:**

```
let writeToFile (filePath:string) (message:string) =
    let file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(filePath)
    file.WriteLine(message)
    file.Close()

let makeInitialDeposit deposit =
    deposit |> insert []

let deposit depositType ((logTransaction:string -> string -> unit), (file:string)) =
    depositType |> makeInitialDeposit
                |> sprintf "Deposited: %f"
                |> logTransaction file

let file = "c:\\myfile.txt"
(writeToFile, file) ||> deposit OneDollarBill
```

Comment: My recommendation would be just not to use the `||>` operator. I know some people in the F# community like it, but I almost never use it because I think it does not make code more readable. You'll need to be more explicit, but I think code without `||>` is easier to understand :)

Comment: @TomasPetricek : IMO calling folds is a case where `||>` is always better because type inference works better when you pipe the state in from the front.

Comment: I don't think banning `||>` gets at the issue here. It's simple syntax sugar with valid uses. If this is enough to cause confusion, it's time to ask why. Scott, you're sometimes asking questions that have straightforward answers in relevant definitions. It might make your programming more efficient to spend some extra time on learning the exact definitions and functionality of used features, so that you can pin down the source of issues with more confidence. When it's perfectly clear how functions, parameters, tuples, and pipes work, the oddness of `||>` here becomes much more prominent.

Comment: Thanks  Vandroiy. You're absolutely right. I used that operator in the past (i.e. couple months ago) and thought I knew how to use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`||>` unpacks a tuple `'a * 'b` to call a normal function `'a -> 'b -> 'c`; as shown, you don't want this unpacking behavior, as you have `'a * 'b -> 'c`.

Either change `||>` to `|>` so the tuple is passed directly:

```
(writeToFile, file) |> deposit OneDollarBill
```

Or change `deposit` to accept curried arguments rather than a tuple:

```
let deposit depositType (logTransaction:string -> string -> unit) (file:string) =
    ...

(writeToFile, file) ||> deposit OneDollarBill
```